# Apache Kafka: Can I set the offset manually

Tags: python, twitter, apache-kafka

So I'm using Apache Kafka as a message queue to relay a Twitter Stream to my consumers. If I want to go back, I want to have a value (offset) which I can send Kafka. So, for eg, if I want to go back one day, I have no idea what the offset would be for that.

Hence, can I set the offset manually? Maybe a linux/epoch timestamp?

Answer (score 0):

Don't see how that would be possible, but instead you can:

- Use Kafka's API to obtain an offset that is earlier than a given time (getOffsetBefore). Note that the granularity depends on your storage file size IIRC and thus you can get an offset that is quite a bit earlier than the time you specified
- Keep a timestamp in the message itself and use it in conjunction with above to skip messages
- Keep an external index of time->offset yourself and use that

Comment: Can't find the getOffsetBefore anywhere on the Kafka API docs. Could you link me to it, though?

Comment: @SarthakDev here you go: https://github.com/kafka-dev/kafka/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/kafka/consumer/SimpleConsumer.scala#L153